# Opcode Cache after successful deployment of TYPO3 project using Surf

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I am deploying a TYPO3 6.2 project with (current master of) Surf. Both `EXT:typo3_console` (1.1.8) and `EXT:coreapi` (1.3.0) are installed (in the most current compatible versions) and activated in the TYPO3 project.

Unfortunatelly I get an error when requesting the successfully deployed project in the browser:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class tx_pdfcreator2 in /var/www/vhosts/preview/htdocs/releases/20161122165450/Web/typo3conf/ext/pdf_creator2/class.tx_pdfcreator2.php on line 37
```

After clearing the Opcode Cache in TYPO3's Install Tool the TYPO3 instance works again.

Clearing the Opcode Cache via `EXT:coreapi` does not solve the problem although the output on the console is "The complete opcode cache has been cleared".

This is the output Surf generates:

```
Deploying preview (20161122165450)
Stage initialize
Webserver 001 (Project_001) TYPO3\Surf\Task\CreateDirectoriesTask
Webserver 001 (Project_001) TYPO3\Surf\Task\Generic\CreateDirectoriesTask
Stage package
Webserver 001 (Project_001) TYPO3\Surf\Task\Package\GitTask
Webserver 001 (Project_001) Foo\Deployment\Task\LocalInstallTask
Stage transfer
Webserver 001 (Project_001) TYPO3\Surf\Task\Transfer\RsyncTask
Webserver 001 (Project_001) TYPO3\Surf\Task\Generic\CreateSymlinksTask
Webserver 001 (Project_001) TYPO3\Surf\Task\TYPO3\CMS\CreatePackageStatesTask
Stage update
Webserver 001 (Project_001) TYPO3\Surf\Task\TYPO3\CMS\SymlinkDataTask
Webserver 001 (Project_001) TYPO3\Surf\Task\TYPO3\CMS\CopyConfigurationTask
Stage migrate
Webserver 001 (Project_001) TYPO3\Surf\Task\TYPO3\CMS\SetUpExtensionsTask
Webserver 001 (Project_001) TYPO3\Surf\Task\TYPO3\CMS\CompareDatabaseTask
Stage finalize
Stage test
Stage switch
Webserver 001 (Project_001) TYPO3\Surf\Task\SymlinkReleaseTask
Node "Webserver 001" is live!
Webserver 001 (Project_001) TYPO3\Surf\Task\TYPO3\CMS\FlushCachesTask
Stage cleanup
Webserver 001 (Project_001) TYPO3\Surf\Task\CleanupReleasesTask
Removing releases 20161117180245
```

Any idea what went wrong here and how I could solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clear opcode caches with surf you need to add the WebOpcacheResetCreateScriptTask and WebOpcacheResetExecuteTask tasks to your workflow.

Clearing opcode caches on cli with coreapi will do nothing. See http://insight.helhum.io/post/142295674970/what-you-need-to-know-about-php-opcode-cache for a detailed explenation

Comment: Thank you for a great link. Just one thing: disabling `opcache.validate_timestamps` in TYPO3 would mean, that one must have a correct `opcache.blacklist_filename` provided, which includes `LocalConfiguration.php`, `PackageStates.php`, everything in `typo3temp/`. Something else? Or, maybe, you know some resource, where one can read about Opcache tubning for TYPO3?

Comment: It heavily depends on your setup and deployment strategy. If you only change code and configuration during deployment (recommended), you don't need any backlists as PHP files will only change after deployment.

Comment: I partly agree here, bcs even if config files are changed during deployment only, the TYPO3 administrator may want to change some extension settings during site lifetime, which would be written to LocalConfiguration.php, but would not be detected due to disabled `validate_timestamps` in Opcache. Same with cache files - I guess they are created/updated/removed also during normal site lifetime.

Comment: I would not recommend such runtime changes to the application, but indeed they are quite common. For that, TYPO3 itself flushes the OpcodeCache dynamically when such changes occur.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about auto-flush. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

Using the Surf tasks `\TYPO3\Surf\Task\Php\WebOpcacheResetCreateScriptTask` and `\TYPO3\Surf\Task\Php\WebOpcacheResetExecuteTask` (which come with Surf) instead of `EXT:coreapi` worked for me!

```
$workflow->addTask(WebOpcacheResetCreateScriptTask::class, 'package', $this);
$workflow->addTask(WebOpcacheResetExecuteTask::class, 'switch', $this);
```

Comment: 2 things you have to add to make this tasks work: $this->setOption('scriptBasePath', 'path/to/web/folder/on/build/server']);
$this->setOption('baseUrl', https://url-deploy-target-server.tld;